# Upload 1 missing DSYM required to process 18 crashes in firebase crash report

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement firebase crash report in Xamarin forms for IOS APP .I did all the setups according to Firebase documentation .I am using visual studio for windows and I  manually crashed the app and when I tried to see the crash report in firebase console it is showing error.

[image]

Comment: Did you upload any dSYMs?

Comment: No,I didn't upload dSYMs ..

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when building a program, certain information is lost. The process of compilation is lossy and not (completely) reversable. Information that is lost includes

- Line numbers relative to the original source code
- Names of local variables
- The exact structure of code
- ...

(Please note that the extent of this totally depends on which language you use. With C# and C++/CLI more information is retained than with native C++ or other languages that are compiled to native binaries.)

When debugging an application, this information is kept in `.pdb` files (and to some extent in the binary itself, I believe), but applications that are released usually lack this information, because you'd not want them to be bloated and slow, but sleek and fast. iOS apps are compiled to native binaries anyway AFAIK, which renders names of methods unreadable. Xcode still builds some debugging information (**d**ebugging **SYM**bols it is, I think) you can use to retroactively analyze errors to a greater extent that it would be possible without any debugging information, if the errors are recorded in any way (e.g. with AppCenter and obviously Firebase).

There seems to be a [Firebase script](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports#run-upload-symbols-script-manually) you can use to upload the `.dSYM` file. From your image it seems to me that there are some facilities to upload the file from the web interface, too (the `.dSYM` file is a folder, actually, AppCenter for example needs it to be zipped). After uploading the symbols, you should get a decent stack trace with named methods. **Anyway** I don't think that you can obtain them easily if you did not store them after building your app. Since this release seems to be uploaded for testing purposes only, you seem to be lucky. Just rebuild it and upload the `.dSYM` that should be located in the same folder your `.ipa` is located in.